# TextArea output from a List

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I am having trouble with modifying output from a List (called "cds") inside a JTextArea (from JFrame)......

When I run displayButtonActionPerformed, it places all objects in the array into the JTextArea.

However, these objects are strung together with commas in one big list....
Is there any code which would remove the commas, and create a newline between each object.....

The array can be arbitrarily large, so simply doing a collections.size(0) then /n then collections.size(1) and then /n........will not work.

My code is as follows:

```
private void displayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // sorts then displays entries in the array
    Collections.sort(cds, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    outputArea.setText(cds.toString());
}
```

The line in question is:

```
outputArea.setText(cds.toString());
```

This is what they DO look like in the JTextArea:

```
[Abbey Road -- Beatles, Alive -- Doors, Gimme Shelter -- Rolling Stones, Hey Jude -- Beatles, Staying Alive -- Beegees]
```

This is what they SHOULD look like in the JTextArea:

```
Abbey Road -- Beatles
Alive -- Doors
Gimme Shelter -- Rolling Stones
Hey Jude -- Beatles
Staying Alive -- Beegees
```

P.S., I'm not having trouble currently removing the brackets, but if anyone knew a simple way, that'd be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `append` instead of `setText` and a loop

---

### Solution

```
for (Object o : cds){
    outputArea.append(o + "\n");
}
```

---

### Output

[image]

Comment: @3.14ed_Piper Actually, you're using a Collection, not an array, therefor, here is the solution.

Comment: @3.14ed_Piper There's no difference with this solution but if you use `toString()` on an array, you will get a hashcode and not the values contained in it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the results you want, you can create a class or function that takes an array as an argument and prints out the items within it in the format you like:

```
....
public static String printArray (String[] textArray) {
    String output = "";
    for (String s : textArray) {
        output += s + '\n';
    }
    return output;
}
...
private void displayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // sorts then displays entries in the array
    Collections.sort(cds, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    outputArea.setText(printArray(cds));  //Change this line
}
```

After adding a similar method to the one I have shown, change the last line in your `displayButtonActionPerformed()` method as shown.

I have tested the `printArray()` method in a similar example.